# Does Javascript have a higher level API for accessing cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

All the cookie handling examples I've seen for Javascript treat cookies as a string and do their own splitting and parsing etc.

Before I do this myself by hand, I want to check that there isn't a higher level API already available in, say, HTML5 / new javascript, for treating cookies as an associative array or something.

Is there?

Comment: It doesn't but cookies are starting to be deprecated - use `localStorage`. If you still want to use cookies there are libraries to make it more pleasant like https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: There are *plenty* of libraries for this, no need to roll your own.  (I agree with @Slim that localStorage is a better choice for clientside storage, though)

Comment: @Slim The server cannot access the `localStorage`. `localStorage` works for storing data unless you need server sessions. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct, that's why I extended my previous comment that in such cases you may use a lib that provides better API for managing cookies.

Comment: Just stringify and store an object as a string in the cookie and then parse it into JSON on the front-end or back-end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively no. The `document.cookie` property holds the cookies, as a string, as you mention, and simply sends that string in the `Cookie` request header of the requests.

Then, wherever you need these cookies to be parsed (either on the client by accessing the `document.cookie` or on the server by accessing the `Cookie` request header), you have to implement your own parser or use one built already.

For storing things on the client side, you can use `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", "42");
localStorage.getItem("foo");
// => "42"
```

But again, the server has no access to the `localStorage`.